# what happened to the shuffle option in iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipod

Can anyone tell me how to get my iPod touch to shuffle my full music library with iTunes 12.1.0.50?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a playlist with all of your music in iTunes, add that playlist to you iPod, and then when you select the playlist, you are given the option to shuffle the playlist at that top of the list.

Comment: Also as the accepted answer in the link posted by Jaime Santa Cruz shows, you need to start playing a song to access shuffle. Adding a playlist lets you start shuffle from the top of the list, similar to the way Apple had in before in songs.